# Check property of the object inside another object

Tags: php, object, properties

Not very good at objects. Can you please help me to check if "Street_date" property exist within the following object:

```
stdClass Object(    
  [groupOp] => AND       
  [rules] => Array(        
    [0] => stdClass Object(
       [field] => Street_Date
       [op] => le
       [data] => 2014-02-01
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: `$obj->rules[0]->field=='Street_Date'` or what do you mean?

Comment: @Rufinus what if Street_Date not necessarily at position 0 in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want to do. Say `$arrObj` is the object array you have

```
foreach($arrObj->rules as $key=>$val){
  if(isset($val->field) && $val->field == 'Street_Date'){
     echo 'Found';
     exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is it, just hoped i could do something like `property_exist($obj->rules,"Street_Date")` but thanks for the code

Comment: `Street_Date` isn't the name of a property, it's the value.